# How to add custom columns to Pivot Table (similar to Grand Total)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have data which I pivot as `Row Labels` and `Column Labels` which gives me something like this:

[image]

And what I would like to do is add columns like `Grand Total` (i.e. which applies to all columns as a whole, and not each column individually) to calculate things such as `Average`, `Min`, `Max`, `Standard Deviation`.....

I have found a way to change the `Grand Total` column (more options gives you more calculations like standard dev):

[image]

[image]

However I can't find a way to add more columns (i.e. I would like to keep `Grand Total`, and add more columns for `Average`, `Min`, `Max`, `Standard Deviation`

**How can I add a calculated column to my pivot table in a similar way to Grand Total?**

UPDATE: Adding a calculated field to my pivot table

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

However whatever I do, my calculated field shows the same as the `SUM`.

**Am I doing something wrong with the calculated field?**

Comment: You could add a field. Click on the PivotTable, go to the tab PivotTable Tools at the top > Options > Fields, Items & Sets > Calculated Field. From there you could add fields which will then be added to the grand total. The downside is that you will have twice the number of columns for one additional field, thrice for 2 additional, etc.

Comment: @Jerry: I tried to add calculated field, but whatever I do, I get the same as the sum. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not a calculated field, but a **calculate item**.

Your column field has 12 items, namely the 12 months of a year. What you want is an additional column called `Avg`. So we need to add `Avg` besides the 12 items:

Activate (click on) any cell with a label of the column field, say the cell with `Jan`, then PivotTable tools -> Options -> Fields, Items & Sets -> Calculated Item (it is dimmed if you do not activate a cell for field labels.) Then, name a new item `Avg` and set the formula `=AVERAGE(Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)`

Add other calculated items similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easist solution to your problem is to drag the field you want to operate on (Temperature) again into values and then choose "Average" instead of "Sum" in the "summarize vlaues by" menu available after right clicking. Min, Max are available.